# If I'm testing an rspec extension, how do I suppress the results of tests which fail as part of the test?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to write specs for an extension to rspec.

This is the gist of what I'm trying to test:

```
require 'rspec-let-and-after-extension'

RSpec.describe "let(...).and_after" do
  it 'is called if the `let` is invoked even if the example fails' do
    call_order = []

    RSpec.describe do
      let(:foo) { }.and_after { call_order << :and_after }
      it { foo; call_order << :example; raise 'failed!' }
    end.run

    expect(call_order).to eq [:example, :and_after]
  end
end
```

One of the important behaviours is that if running the example fails, the cleanup code still runs. So I test this by recording the order of the calls and raising an exception from the example.

Problem is, when I run it, it sees this block as a second example, which then fails with errors:

```
.F

Failures:

  1)  
     Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:

     1.1) Failure/Error: it { foo; call_order << :example; raise 'failed!' }
          RuntimeError:
            failed!
          # ./spec/spec.rb:43:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
          # ./spec/spec.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

     1.2) Failure/Error: it { foo; call_order << :example; raise 'failed!' }
          RuntimeError:
            failed!
          # ./spec/spec.rb:43:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00167 seconds (files took 0.08011 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/spec.rb:43 #
```

As you can see, the output did have one dot, so the actual example *passed*. But then there is an F, because it has seen the internal example, run that, and unsurprisingly that one failed.

How do I make rspec not see this nested example as one of the examples it's supposed to run, so that this example completes with a single dot?

(If you're wondering about what the rspec devs themselves do about *their* tests, it looks like they use cucumber. Do they use cucumber because they couldn't figure this out either? :))

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new [sandboxing API](http://rspec.info/blog/2015/02/rspec-3-2-has-been-released/#core-new-sandboxing-api) (available in 3.2+).

```
RSpec.configure do |rspec|
  rspec.around do |ex|
    RSpec::Core::Sandbox.sandboxed do |config|
      # re-configure any configuration defined by your extension here
      # before allowing the example to run. The sandbox runs with a fresh
      # config instance, which means any configuration you have set in
      # `rspec-let-and-after-extension` will not apply while the example
      # is running.
      # config.extend MyExtensionModule
      ex.run
    end
  end
end
```